# How to send xon/xoff in case of binary data?

Tags: uart, flow-control

In case of software data flow control, we use xon and xoff (0x11 and 0x13) standard characters to pause and resume transmission. But if we want to send binary data which contains characters which match with the ascii value of xon and xoff, what character set should we use to send xon or xoff ?

Comment: You need to design an application protocol that allows you to encode control characters instead of sending them raw.

Comment: *"what character set should we use to send xon or xoff"* -- Termios will let you (re)define the values for soft flow control, but that doesn't help when transferring binary data.  Either encode all of the binary data (e.g. uuencode/uudecode, Intel or Motorola hex) or employ an `escape` character sequence (so that data that do match XON & XOFF can be "escaped" or encoded).

Answer (score 1):

I simple solution is to use base64 encoding, which you have it in python ..

```
base64.b64encode(yourData) - encode
base64.b64decode(yourData) - decode,
```

it adds the additional overhead but the sent data is in simple character format. even HDLC used base64 so this will be one option for you I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Using software handshaking precludes the sending of binary data.

Short of doing something esoteric (sending 9 bits/byte instead of 8 - very non-standard) there is no distinction between 2 of the 256 different binary data and the 2 codes selected for uses as XON/XOFF.

There are various protocols that attempt to deal with this.  They all encode the "binary data" into something efficient but not a one-to-one mapping.  One can use escape codes, compression, data packets, etc.  Of course, both ends of the communication need to know how to encode/decode.  This often limits your choices.  If in doubt, start with Binary-to-text encoding as it tends to be easier to debug.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use those two special characters as control ones, you have to make sure they do not occur in the payload data. One way to do that is to encode payload with a reduced alphabet that does not include the special characters. The binary-to-text encodings mentioned in a parallel answer would do the job, but if low overhead not depending on distribution of input bytes is critical, then the [escapeless](https://github.com/kosarev/escapeless) encoding may help.